# If we log a Firebase event when Internet is unavailable, will that event be sent later?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

In my Android app, I'm logging an event and want to know if Firebase sends that event after Internet is available.

Firebase documentation does not mention anything about that

Comment: Is this with Firebase Analytics?

Comment: @AL. yes, it is with Firebase Analytics